# Sum the counts of the unique elements of a group and keep the one with the highest value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy

I have a large dataset that looks like this

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(col1= c("a","a","k","k","k"), col2 = c("a1","a2","k1","k2","k3"),
             distance = c(1,1,1,1,1),
             count_col1=c(1,1,4,4,4), count_col2=c(3,4,1,1,1))
df
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   col1  col2  distance count_col1 count_col2
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 a     a1           1          1          3
#> 2 a     a2           1          1          4
#> 3 k     k1           1          4          1
#> 4 k     k2           1          4          1
#> 5 k     k3           1          4          1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This dataset is derived after comparing the strings

```
a with a1
a with a2
k with k1
.....
k with k3
```

***distance***:
the column distance, that should not play a role, shows the levenhstein distance between each pair of characters.

***count_col1***:
count_col1 refers to the counts of the elements in col1 and
***count_col2***:
count_col2 refers to the counts of the elements in col2.

I group my observations based on col1, and then I have two groups:
***group a*** and ***group k***.

I want:

1. In each group to keep the element with the highest count,
   which is the a2 in group a, and the k in the group k.
2. At the same time I want to sum the counts of each unique element per group.

**I want my data to look like this**

```
 col     sum_counts
  a2      8 
  k       7
```

**EDIT:**

---

in group k, the element with the highest value is the element k.
I want to group all the elements in group k under the k element because it has the highest counts.
I do not want to count element k more than once. I want to count it only once.

k=4, and then I want to add the counts of the rest of the unique group members
which are k1=1, k2=1, k3=1.
For this the sum is : sum = k + k1 + k2 + k3
sum =7

**In the group a**
the element with the highest count is the element a2.
the count of a2 = 4.
there is two times a and I do not want to count it twice.
so the outcome would be  a2 + a1 + a = 8

Comment: Why is sum_counts = 7 for group k ?

Comment: The sum of those by group is not equal to that value in expected

Comment: Why is the first entry of `col` `a2`? Should it be `a`?

Comment: These are very useful questions. I ll try to explain better! Thank you so much for taking the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems very strange that you don't want the group preserved in the output, but here you go:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  summarize(
    col = if(max(count_col1) > max(count_col2)) {
      first(col1) 
    } else {
      col2[which.max(count_col2)]
    },
    sum_counts = sum(unique(count_col1), count_col2),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  select(-col1)
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   col   sum_counts
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 a2             8
# 2 k              7
```

Comment: thank you @Gregor Thomas. Very neat and delicate, my script was significantly longer